# Can MyISAM tables affect the backup recovery of innodb tables on Amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, amazon-rds

I have an Amazon RDS instance containing several databases. All the tables are innnodb except from one, that is MyISAM and currently cannot be converted to innodb.

I know that the recovery of MyISAM tables are not guaranteed by Amazon, I just want to know if this MyISAM table can affect the recovery of the other (innodb) tables.